# In R how can I multiply values of certain columns from two data frames where the columns have matching names

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have two data frames. Both data frames have the same column names. The `Period` and `Code` column values match (ie. the combination of them is a key).

For rows where the keys match I want to multiply the value of column `a` from dataframe1 with column `a` value from dataframe2, and the same for column `c`. I'm thinking the solution might involve a left join.

Here are the dataframes:

**dataframe1:**

| Period | Code | a | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-13 | ABC | 1 | 8 |
| 2015-01-13 | ABC | 2 | 9 |
| 2015-01-13 | LMZ | 3 | 10 |
| 2016-01-13 | LMZ | 4 | 11 |

**dataframe2:**

| Period | Code | a | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-13 | ABC | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| 2015-01-13 | ABC | 0.5 | 0.9 |
| 2015-01-13 | EKZ | 0.9 | 0.3 |
| 2015-01-13 | LMZ | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 2016-01-13 | LMZ | 0.3 | 0.4 |

Code to re-create data frames:

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(Period=c(as.Date("2014-01-13"), as.Date("2015-01-13"),as.Date("2015-01-13"),as.Date("2016-01-13") ),Code = c("ABC","ABC","LMZ","LMZ"), a = 1:4, c=8:11)

dataframe2 <- data.frame(Period=c(as.Date("2014-01-13"),as.Date("2015-01-13"),as.Date("2015-01-13"),as.Date("2015-01-13"),as.Date("2016-01-13")),Code = c("ABC","ABC","EKZ","LMZ","LMZ"), a = c(0.1,0.5,0.9,0.4,0.3), c=c(0.2,0.9,0.3,0.2,0.4))
```

This is what I am hoping to get:

**newDataframe:**

| Period | Code | a | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-13 | ABC | 0.1 | 1.6 |
| 2015-01-13 | ABC | 1 | 8.1 |
| 2015-01-13 | LMZ | 1.2 | 2 |
| 2016-01-13 | LMZ | 1.2 | 4.4 |

For example, here the numeric values from row 1 in dataframe1 have been multiplied by the matching values from the row with the matching key in dataframe2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a left_join (`dplyr::left_join`), as you indicate, and then deselect the no-longer-needed columns:

```
library(dplry)

left_join(dataframe1, dataframe2, by=c("Period", "Code")) %>% 
  mutate(a=a.x*a.y, c=c.x*c.y) %>% 
  select(-c(a.x:c.y))
```

Output

```
      Period Code   a   c
1 2014-01-13  ABC 0.1 1.6
2 2015-01-13  ABC 1.0 8.1
3 2015-01-13  LMZ 1.2 2.0
4 2016-01-13  LMZ 1.2 4.4
```

A data.table solution is here:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dataframe2)[
  setDT(dataframe1),on=.(Period, Code),.(Period, Code, a = a*i.a, c=c*i.c)
]
```

Output:

```
       Period Code   a   c
1: 2014-01-13  ABC 0.1 1.6
2: 2015-01-13  ABC 1.0 8.1
3: 2015-01-13  LMZ 1.2 2.0
4: 2016-01-13  LMZ 1.2 4.4
```